# terraform hetzner firewall apply to node

Tags: terraform, devops, firewall

Mainly issue is that's i cant use apply_to in firewall with vars

```
resource "hcloud_firewall" "appf" {
  name = "appf"
  apply_to {
    server = var.app-f-ids
  }

  rule {
    direction = "in"
    protocol  = "tcp"
    port      = "443"
    source_ips = [
      "0.0.0.0/0",
      "::/0"
    ]
  }

  rule {
    direction = "in"
    protocol  = "tcp"
    port      = "6379"
    source_ips = "${formatlist("%s/32", concat(var.app-ips, var.app-f-ips))}"
  }
}

resource "hcloud_firewall_attachment" "appf_attach" {
    firewall_id = hcloud_firewall.appf.id
    server_ids  = var.app-f-ids
```

}
While second block with hcloud_firewall_attachment works fine, first can't attach node to firewall cause `Inappropriate value for attribute "server": number required.` with the same variable
Any ideas?

Any suggestions how to fix it

Answer (score 0):

Because my var is array, with only 1 ID, (but it is still an array), therefore I should use `[0]` in the end of var.